# ¿Cómo cambio el estilo de estos botones en la ventana de Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me parece ilegible, se supone que puedo cambiarlo desde custom theme pero no encuentro la opcion, ayuda, gracias. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cambiar color al Botón…
En la ventana propiedades busque la propiedad BackColor

De clic en la pestaña de la derecha y verá  la siguiente ventana…

Seleccione Personalizado  y se desplegará la paleta de colores…

Escoja el sexto cuadrito de la tercera fila…
Y obtendrá lo siguiente…

El control botón ha cambiado de color.
Para que todos los cambios vayan teniendo efecto, el botón tiene que estar seleccionado.
Cambiar el color de la letra de un control:
El cambio de color de la letra se hace usando la propiedad ForeColor.

Dé clic en la pestaña del Ítem de esta propiedad y verá lo siguiente…

Dé clic en cualquiera de las tres opciones Personalizado, Web o Sistema…
En el ejemplo se escogió el menú Web y luego el color rojo…

Al dar clic, la ventana de propiedades quedó así…

Y las letras del botón quedaron así…

Modificar el tamaño y tipo de letra en un control:
Se logra usando la propiedad Font

De clic en los puntos suspensivos y se abrirá la siguiente ventana…

En Fuente seleccione Arial, en Estilo seleccione Negrita y en Tamaño seleccione 20 y luego dé clic en Aceptar.

Ahora observe que el tipo, tamaño y estilo de letra ha cambiado en el control Button.

Insertar imagen en el Botón
El procedimiento es el mismo que se hizo para insertar imagen en el formulario, usando la propiedad BackgroundImage.

Dé clic en los puntos suspensivos, en la ventana que se abre, ponga un check en Recurso Local, luego en Importar…se abrirá una ventana en donde puede navegar por las imágenes de su ordenador, una vez que eligió la imagen, dé clic en Abrir, luego se abrirá otra ventana en donde debe dar clic en Aceptar y quedará así…

Por supuesto que la imagen será diferente, según la escogida; Otra cosa que sucede con alguna frecuencia es que la imagen se despliega en todo el formulario y no solo en el botón, esto ocurre porque no se seleccionó el control Botón o algún clic adicional dimos que provocó  que el control botón quedara sin selección. Si la imagen no  se despliega correctamente es porque la propiedad BackGroundImageLayout no está en Stretch por lo que aplique esta propiedad y verá como la imagen se despliega adecuadamente.
Quite la imagen del botón usando la misma propiedad BackGroundImage y en la ventana que se abre dé clic en Borrar y luego Aceptar… la imagen desaparecerá del control y volverá al color que le habíamos puesto.
Moviendo un Botón en el formulario:
Se puede ubicar un control en cualquier lugar del formulario, arrastrándolo con el puntero del mouse  sin tocar los bordes.
Intente hacerlo y verá qué fácil es.
Ahora observe el código del botón, dando clic derecho en el mouse  y luego clic en Código y verá una ventana parecida a la siguiente.

Fíjese en la línea que señala la flecha, ese es el nombre del botón (Button1_Click) lo que significa que el botón se llama Button1 y que responde al evento Clic.
Ahora vuelva al diseñador usando el menú que está encima de la ventana de código y dé clic en Form.vb

A continuación, seleccione el Botón, abra las propiedades y busque el Ítem (Name) observe que se llama Button1 y por eso es que en el código aparece con ese nombre.

Si se inserta otro botón en el mismo proyecto, Visual Basic le asignará el nombre Button2, Button3 y así sucesivamente.
Pero debemos cambiarlo, como ya lo hicimos, para  poder reconocer para que sirve.
Agregue  tres botones más….usando el método que quiera…usted conoce muchos y si no recuerda como, entonces, vuelva a leer lo explicado anteriormente.
Es bueno no acostumbrarse a usar un solo método para dibujar controles en el formulario, ejecutar un programa, desplegar la ventana de propiedades etc., porque se olvidan los métodos que no se practican; por lo que lo invito a que use periódicamente los diferentes métodos para ejecutar una acción.

Alineando Controles:
Visual Basic tiene guías para  ayudar a alinear controles en el formulario.
A medida que arrastra con el  puntero del mouse un control y pasa cerca de otros controles, se visualizan unas líneas azules que se ubican entre un control y otro.
Si nosotros soltamos el mouse en el  momento que están las líneas azules, el control quedará en línea recta con el otro.

Las líneas Azules orientan en la alineación vertical pero si la alineación es horizontal la línea guía será color rosada y está ubicada un poco cerca del centro del control como puede ver en la imagen siguiente…

También las líneas guías azules y rosadas nos sirven para referencia, cuando los controles son de diferente tamaño y queremos ponerles a todos, o algunos de ellos, el mismo tamaño.
Otra cosa es que los controles a alinear pueden ser de diferente categoría, por ejemplo puede ser un listbox y un botón o un control Label y un botón o cualquier  otra combinación.
Borrar un control del formulario:
Para borrar un control del formulario se da clic derecho en el mouse sobre el control y aparece el siguiente menú…

Dé clic en  Eliminar y se borrará el control.
Otra forma es, seleccionar el control y luego presionar la tecla suprimir.
Como hacer que el Botón responda al presionar la tecla Enter
A veces queremos que un botón responda al presionar la tecla Enter o Intro.
Esto se logra, modificando la propiedad AcceptButton en la ventana de propiedades del formulario…

Abra la pestaña…

Observe que en este cuadro aparecen todos los botones que hay en el formulario pero solo puede escoger uno para que responda al presionar la tecla Enter.
En este caso, busque BtnMinombre y una vez que se programe el botón con este nombre y se ejecute el programa este botón responderá al dar Enter.
Ahora borre todos los botones y solo deje el de Mi nombre es…
Cierre el proyecto desde el menú Archivo------ > Guardar todo del menú archivo.
Esto hará que el programa Visual Basic guarde todos los archivos del proyecto, incluyendo los cambios que usted le ha hecho.

Y luego cierre el programa Visual Basic, usando Salir del menú Archivo o en el botón  (X)

Comment: Este no es un windows form, es la ventana de Agregar Proyecto del propio Visual Studiio, entiendo lo que me dices pero no es un proyecto,